# How can I make changes to a path string that exists within a variable (as part of a loop)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently developing a loop where for each csv in the directory I am re-sampling and then saving as a new csv. However, I would like to retain only part of the original path string contained within the variable so that I can add an identifier for the new file.

For example, the file picked up through the loop may be:

```
'...\folder1\101_1000_RoomTemperatures.csv'
```

But I would like the new saved file to look like:

```
'...\folder2\101_1000_RoomTemperatures_Rounded.csv'
```

Have noticed SQL and C-related posts about this issue - however, solutions I suspect not relevant for within the python environment. Using the code below I can rename the outputs to enable differentiation, however, not ideal!

```py
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):

        # Pull in the file
        df = pd.read_csv(filename)

        # actions occur here

        # Export the file
        df.to_csv('{}_rounded.csv'.format(str(filename)))
```

The output using this code is:

```
'...\folder1\101_1000_RoomTemperatures.csv_rounded.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to split by dots and omit the part after the last dot to get the base filename (without file extension):

```
>>> filename = r'...\folder1\101_1000_RoomTemperatures.csv'
>>> filename
'...\\folder1\\101_1000_RoomTemperatures.csv'
>>> base_filename = '.'.join(filename.split('.')[:-1])
>>> base_filename
'...\\folder1\\101_1000_RoomTemperatures'
```

Then use this `base_filename` to give the new name:

```
df.to_csv('{}_rounded.csv'.format(base_filename))
```